# Find Next Record Command Button

Tags: excel, vba

I need your help,

I can't seem to get the next or previous buttons to work with the .FindNext and FindPrevious functions of excel.

My aim is to create a user form where the user can use the next and prev buttons to go back and fourth between the found matches of "test". I thought that by globalizing the variable foundCell, I might be able to accomplish this, but I was epically wrong.

```
Dim foundCell

Private Sub btnSearch_Click()

    With Sheet1
        Set foundCell = .Cells.find(What:="test", After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    End With

    If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox ("""Bingo"" found in row " & foundCell.Row)
            form1.location.Value = Cells(foundCell.Row, 1).Value
    Else
            MsgBox ("Bingo not found")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btnNext_Click()
    foundCell.FindNext
    form1.location.Value = Cells(foundCell.Row, 1).Value
End Sub

Private Sub btnPrev_Click()
    foundCell.FindPrevious
    form1.location.Value = Cells(foundCell.Row, 1).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: so what is it not doing?

Comment: finding the next and prev values of my search

Comment: if you put all your found values in an array, you could go trough the array of values back and forth ........ see suggested code in your previous post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take your search routine and move it into a sub routine.  Then you can just call it by passing in a few params. like the starting cell to search from and which direction to go.

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click()
dosearch Cells(1, 1), Excel.xlNext
End Sub

Private Sub btnNext_Click()
    dosearch foundCell, Excel.xlNext
End Sub

Private Sub btnPrev_Click()
    dosearch foundCell, Excel.xlPrevious
End Sub

Sub dosearch(r As Range, whichWay As Integer)
With Sheet1
        Set foundCell = .Cells.Find(What:="test", After:=r, _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=whichWay, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
End With

    If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox ("""Bingo"" found in row " & foundCell.Row)
            form1.Location.Value = Cells(foundCell.Row, 1).Value
    Else
            MsgBox ("Bingo not found")
    End If

End Function
```